# Second nav-bar not expanding after being collapsed?

Tags: javascript

In this simple expand/collapse navbar I made, the second navbar does not re-expand once it is collapsed, though the first one works fine.
Once I collapse the second section, it stays collapsed and will not expand, though the first section continues to work fine, expanding and collapsing
Thanks, all help is appreciated.

Here is my code below:

```
<script>
        var CurrentSec;
        var CurrentMenu;
        var CurrentLink;
        function Change(sec, state) {
            CurrentSec = "Sec-"+sec;
            CurrentMenu = "Menu-"+sec;
            CurrentLink = "Link-"+sec;
            if (state == 0) {
                document.getElementById(CurrentSec).src = "http://www.pirates-online-rewritten.com/Images/collapsed.gif";
                document.getElementById(CurrentMenu).style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById(CurrentLink).href = "javascript:Change("+sec+", 1)";
            }
            else {
                document.getElementById(CurrentSec).src = "http://www.pirates-online-rewritten.com/Images/expanded.gif";
                document.getElementById(CurrentMenu).style.display = "inline";
                document.getElementById(CurrentLink).href = "javascript:Change("+sec+", 0)";
            }

        }
    </script>
    <div class="sdmenu" style="visibility:visible">
        <span class="title" id="community"><img src="http://www.pirates-online-rewritten.com/Images/clear.gif" class="menuspacer" width="131" height="15" alt="Pirates Community" /><a href="javascript:Change(1, 0)" id="Link-1"><img src="http://www.pirates-online-rewritten.com/Images/expanded.gif" class="arrow" alt="Close Menu" id="Sec-1"/></a></span>
            <div id="Navbar"><div class="submenu" id="Menu-1">
            <a id="Link-1" >Test1</a>
            <a id="Link-2" >Test2</a>
            <a id="Link-3" >Test3</a>
            <a id="Link-4" >Test4</a>
            <a href="javascript:void(null)"></a>
            <span class="menubottom" id="menubottom">    
                <img src="http://www.pirates-online-rewritten.com/Images/boxbot.gif" alt="-" />
            </span>
         </div>
            <span class="title" id="community">
                <img src="http://www.pirates-online-rewritten.com/Images/clear.gif" class="menuspacer" width="131" height="15" alt="Pirates Community" />
                    <a href="javascript:Change(2, 0)" id="Link-2"><img src="http://www.pirates-online-rewritten.com/Images/expanded.gif" class="arrow" alt="Close Menu" id="Sec-2"/></a>
                </span>
            <div id="Navbar">
                <div class="submenu" id="Menu-2">
                    <a id="Link-1" >Test5</a>
                    <a id="Link-2" >Test6</a>
                    <a id="Link-3" >Test7</a>
                    <a id="Link-4" >Test8</a>
                    <a href="javascript:void(null)"></a>
                    <span class="menubottom" id="menubottom">
                        <img src="http://www.pirates-online-rewritten.com/Images/boxbot.gif" alt="-" />
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: here, this is your javascript and html in a jsfiddle , you want to edit css  , or do someothing to get it closer to working so we can help  http://jsfiddle.net/2gqR2/

Comment: Sorry, didn't post my CSS. I will try to find it (I have it scattered between files)

Comment: no , don't just post the css, edit that fiddle and get it as close as you can to working